# Share just a version of your code using GitHub

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm trying to use GitHub to share some code with a client. I would like to know if there's a way to share just the last commit made to some branch, in a way that my client can get the code (either with a pull or a fork) without having access to all the previous commits, as the repository is private. Is there a way to do this? The reason I want it this way is so that I don't have to send the whole project every time I need to share the code, as its very heavy. Doing this would give a very easy way to share code without showing the whole history of changes.

Update: 
My question really comes to if there is a way to share the actual status of the project without sharing all the changes through which it has gone.

Comment: how client will get full code while having only last commit? what if some files were introduced by previous commit and are not changed in last one?

Comment: Good point. My real question is if there's a way to share the actual status of the project without sharing all the changes through which it has gone.

Comment: create separate branch and push squashed version of your local commits to it

Comment: With respect, I don't understand the premise of the question: you are doing paid work for a client and want to give them updates _of code_ but don't want to give them access to the code _history_? Why not? I suppose you could you just zip your code and put it on an FTP site somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the that when you're saying share *the status of the project* you don't mean status, but state.

I think the best way would be a demo site.

As for the code I think you could create a separate repo where you push your *squashed* changes at desired points in time.

---

If you're after just the ability to download the source code you can download the zip of your repo from any commit in GitHub:

[image]

Comment: I wish I could +2 your "Clone or download" addition, I completely forgot that was available and more or less does exactly what it sounds like OP wants (my question comment notwithstanding).